# Runtime Error:(53, 45) error: cannot find symbol method checkSelfPermission(RuntimePermissionsActivity,String)

Tags: android, permissions

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
```

My code was compiled successfully without any issue, but when I run it, it throws the error below.

```
Error:(53, 45) error: cannot find symbol method checkSelfPermission(RuntimePermissionsActivity,String)

Error:(78, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(RuntimePermissionsActivity,String[],int)

Error:(120, 43) error: cannot find symbol method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(RuntimePermissionsActivity,String)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's onCreate(), do the processing within the if block: (you are getting the error because you may be asking for permissions with simultaneous processing in the onCreate()):

```
    askForPermissions();
    if(checkForPermission()){
        //Do your processing here
    }
```

The functions are:

```
void askForPermissions(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

boolean checkForPermission(){
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}
```